# matplotlib - polar density plot with counts

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, polar-coordinates

I would like to make a polar contour plot in matplot lib using the file below:

```
t1     theta1     r1
t2     theta2     r2
t3     theta3     r3
....
tN     thetaN     rN
```

The contour value should be the number of points for each mesh around some r and theta values (t values are time).

So my idea was to create a mesh ( like for every 0.1 radian and 5 radial units) and count the number of points for each part. I could write a loop to do the counting and then plot the resultant data.
But I would like to know if there's any way that it can be done without counting the number of points for each individual mesh.

[image]

So basically I want this figure (plotted using plt.scatter) but instead of scatter, I want a contour plot.

Comment: I would assume [`numpy.histogram2d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) to do the job. See also a possibly related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064339/polar-histogram-in-python-for-given-r-theta-and-z-values).

Comment: Thanks, mate!! This was what I was looking for!! You're awesome!